# in_app_purchase not showing price only shows free in android device flutter

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

in_app_purchase not showing price only shows free in android device flutter,
I using in_app_purchase: ^3.0.8, but after update into in_app_purchase: ^3.1.7. The problem is not fixed.

Please anybody help

I am trying but did not find any solutions

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8ua0.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in android below 12 versioned device IAP package does not returns price one return "Free"